# Dynamically set dropdown options based on other dropdown selection

Tags: r, shiny

The following code allows the user to select between 2 datasets in a dropdown and displays all of the columns for the selected dataset. I would like to add a second dropdown that is dynamically cast with the names of the columns in the selected first dropdown so that the user can select to display a single column only. The goal is to be able to add any dataset to the first dropdown and have it's columns listed in the second dropdown.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    selectInput("dataset", label = NULL, choices = c("mtcars", "rock")),
    tableOutput("contents")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  myData <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "rock" = rock,
           "mtcars" = mtcars)
  })
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    myData()
  })
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "myNames",
                      label = "myNames",
                      choices = myData()$names,
                      selected = myData()$names[1])
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    selectInput("dataset", label = NULL, choices = c("mtcars", "rock")),
    uiOutput("selectvar"),
    plotOutput("contents")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  myData <- reactive({get(input$dataset)})
  
  output$selectvar <- renderUI({
    selectInput("varsel", label=NULL, choices=names(myData()), multiple=T)
  })
  
  output$contents <- renderPlot({
    req(input$varsel[1],input$varsel[2])
    ggplot(myData(), aes(x=.data[[input$varsel[1]]], y=.data[[input$varsel[2]]] )) + geom_point()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: winner winner chicken dinner. Thanks

Comment: Can you solve this without using DT? What I really want to do is take the 2 user selected columns and display them in a ggplot output from server

Comment: Thank you again. I was looking for a second dropdown, but this will work